# Export SQL Results To a Three Lines Text File

Tags: c#, winforms

The Below Code Returns the following data into text file from the database.

**Output**

```
InvoiceNo  InvoiceDate   Amount   Vat   Total
001          1/1/2018     200     10    210
002          2/1/2018     300     15    315
```

What i am looking for is to get Amount,Vat and Total in separate line with the same invoice info so Desired out will be like below

**Desired out**

```
   001          1/1/2018     200     
   001          1/1/2018     10
   001          1/1/2018     210
   002          2/1/2018     300
   002          2/1/2018     15
   002          2/1/2018     315
```

Code

```
        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string datetime = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMddHHmmss");
        string LogFolder = @"C:\Log\";
        try
        {
            string FileNamePart = "Invoice";
            string DestinationFolder = @"C:\Destination\";
            string TableName = "Invoice";
            string FileDelimiter = ","; 
            string FileExtension = ".txt";
            SqlConnection SQLConnection = new SqlConnection();
            SQLConnection.ConnectionString = "Data Source = .\\SQLEXPRESS; Initial Catalog =Backoffice; "
               + "Integrated Security=true;";
            string query = "Select * From " + TableName;
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, SQLConnection);
            SQLConnection.Open();
            DataTable d_table = new DataTable();
            d_table.Load(cmd.ExecuteReader());
            SQLConnection.Close();
            string FileFullPath = DestinationFolder + "\\" + FileNamePart + "_" + datetime + FileExtension;
            StreamWriter sw = null;
            sw = new StreamWriter(FileFullPath, false);
            int ColumnCount = d_table.Columns.Count;
            for (int ic = 0; ic < ColumnCount; ic++)
            {
                sw.Write(d_table.Columns[ic]);
                if (ic < ColumnCount - 1)
                {
                    sw.Write(FileDelimiter);
                }
            }
            sw.Write(sw.NewLine);
            foreach (DataRow dr in d_table.Rows)
            {
                for (int ir = 0; ir < ColumnCount; ir++)
                {
                    if (!Convert.IsDBNull(dr[ir]))
                    {
                        sw.Write(dr[ir].ToString());
                    }
                    if (ir < ColumnCount - 1)
                    {
                        sw.Write(FileDelimiter);
                    }
                }
                sw.Write(sw.NewLine);
            }

            sw.Close();
            MessageBox.Show("Done..");

        }
        catch (Exception exception)
        {

        }

    }
```

How can I archives geting Amount,Vat and Total in separate line with Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edit**

I was thinking about this answer and I realized I assumed you would want to use this invoice data elsewhere. If you don't need to use the data elsewhere, you can just use this block of code. It doesn't store the data returned from the sql call in an object.

```
try {
    var invoices = new List<Invoice>();
    using (var SQLConnection = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString)) {
        SQLConnection.Open();
        using (var cmd = new SqlCommand(query, SQLConnection))
        using (var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader()) {
            while (reader.Read()) {
                // Note: You should handle nulls if the sql columns are nullable
                var number = (int)reader["InvoiceNo"];
                var date = (DateTime)reader["InvoiceDate"];
                var amount = (int)reader["Amount"];
                var vat = (int)reader["Vat"];
                var total = (int)reader["Total"];
                var iNumAndDate = $"{number}{FileDelimiter}{date.ToString("M/dd/yyyy")}{FileDelimiter}";

                sw.Write($"{iNumAndDate}{amount}");
                sw.Write($"{iNumAndDate}{vat}");
                sw.Write($"{iNumAndDate}{total}");
                sw.Write(sw.NewLine);
            }
        }
    }
}
catch (Exception exception) {
    // TODO: Handle exceptions
}
```

**Original:**

First, I would make a class to store each Invoice, we'll call it `Invoice`

```
class Invoice
{
    public int Number { get; set; }
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }
    public int Amount { get; set; }
    public int Vat { get; set; }
    public int Total { get; set; }
}
```

Then, just store your data from the dB in a `List<Invoice>` and then loop through this list to write to the file.

```
try {
    var invoices = new List<Invoice>();
    using (var SQLConnection = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString)) 
    {
        SQLConnection.Open();
        using (var cmd = new SqlCommand(query, SQLConnection))
        using (var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader()) 
        {
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                invoices.Add(new Invoice {
                    // Note: You should handle nulls if the sql columns are nullable
                    Number = (int)reader["InvoiceNo"],
                    Date = (DateTime)reader["InvoiceDate"],
                    Amount = (int)reader["Amount"],
                    Vat = (int)reader["Vat"],
                    Total = (int)reader["Total"]
                });
            }
        }
    }

    using (sw = new StreamWriter(FileFullPath, false)) 
    {
        foreach (var invoice in invoices) 
        {
            var iNumAndDate = $"{invoice.Number}{FileDelimiter}{invoice.Date.ToString("M/dd/yyyy")}{FileDelimiter}";
            sw.Write($"{iNumAndDate}{invoice.Amount}");
            sw.Write($"{iNumAndDate}{invoice.Vat}");
            sw.Write($"{iNumAndDate}{invoice.Total}");
            sw.Write(sw.NewLine);
        }
    }
}
catch (Exception exception) 
{
    // TODO: Handle exceptions
}
```

Comment: ERROR : Invalid attempt to read when no data is present. ON THIS LNE  invoices.Add(new Invoice {

Comment: @ayman Whoops, forgot to add the call to reader.Read() I edited the answer to include it.

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this :

```
foreach (DataRow dr in d_table.Rows)
{
   StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
   for (int ir = 0; ir < 3; ir++)
   {
       if (!Convert.IsDBNull(dr[ir]))
       {
          builder.Append(dr[ir].ToString());
       }
       builder.Append(FileDelimiter);       
   }

   var lineStart = builder.ToString();
   for (int ir = 3; ir < 6; ir++)
   {
       if (!Convert.IsDBNull(dr[ir]))
       {

          sw.Write(lineStart);   
          sw.Write(dr[ir].ToString());
          sw.Write(sw.NewLine);
       }

   }


}
```